# Create logical drives from batch

Tags: windows, batch

I have a need to have some logical drives that extend from my C: drive. My C drive is 200gb roughly and the two other drives P: and T: need to be 50Gb each. How can I create these two logical drives using only batch commands?

Comment: Look up `diskpart`.

Comment: Finally got there myself but its been a long road of pain

Comment: @Jakob Bowyer, please describe your "road" as an answer, so other people  with the same problem may solve it too.

Comment: You probably need to also elevate the commands.